# ¿Cómo borrar múltiples elementos de una tabla en plsql?

Tags: sql, plsql, tablas, delete

Estoy teniendo problemas para hacer un **DELETE** de una tabla. Necesito borrar todos los registros excepto algunos (en PLSQL).

Lo que programé fue lo siguiente:

```
DELETE "tabla" WHERE "condicion 1" = 'O' AND "condicion 2" != 
'elemento1','elemento2','elemento3'
/
COMMIT
/
```

Por supuesto esto está mal hecho, quisiera preguntar cómo sería la forma correcta.

Comment: trata de poner el QUERY que estas trabajando, así podremos revisar mejor.

Comment: la instrucción es DELETE FROM table123 WHERE condiciones. Prueba tu sentencia en una tabla de prueba y nos dices qué prblemas tienes. No deberías tener miedo a probar las cosas por tu cuenta primero :)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo que buscas es esto. Eliminar si se cumple la primera condición y cualquiera de las otras tres

```
DELETE FROM "tabla" 
WHERE "condicion 1" = 'O' 
AND ("condicion 2" != 'elemento1' OR "condicion 2" !=  'elemento2' OR "condicion 2" !=  'elemento3')
```

Comment: La instrucción es DELETE FROM tabla...

Comment: Gracias @Alfabravo. Corregido

Answer (score 0):

Otra opción que también funciona y es más concisa, usando la negación del operador "in" es:

```
DELETE FROM "tabla" 
WHERE "condicion 1" = 'O' 
  AND "condicion 2" not in ('elemento1','elemento2','elemento3')
```

Comment: Por favor, visita el apartado de SO sobre lo que se considera un buena respuesta. Comaprto el enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . De no modificarla puede ser eliminada. Gracias

Comment: @JorgeGuz, leí el documento y veo que se resuelve al pregunta, no entendí porqué cree Ud. que no es "buena respuesta".